# Security cam-stop recording after there is no motion at a certain timer

Tags: python, opencv

I have a project of security cams in python and I have been trying to start a recording while there is a motion and stop the recording after there is no motion (about 5 sec without motion, or any time I choose).
I tried to look for a way by myself, but with no success.
I would be happy if I get some help.
thanks.

this is the server:

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct
import time
import cv2
class ServerSecurityCam:
    def __init__(self):
        localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
        server_socket = socket.socket()
        try:
            server_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 65432))
        except:
            print('Bind failed. Error Code :')
        server_socket.listen(10)
        client, address = server_socket.accept()
        data = b''
        x1 = b''
        x2 = b''
        ttl = 0
        payload_size = struct.calcsize("L")
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
        while data != "exit":
            if True:
                while True:

                    # Retrieve message size
                    while len(data) < payload_size:
                        data += client.recv(4096)

                    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
                    data = data[payload_size:]
                    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]

                    # Retrieve all data based on message size
                    while len(data) < msg_size:
                        data += client.recv(4096)

                    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
                    data = data[msg_size:]

                    # Extract frame
                    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

                    # Display
                    cv2.imshow('frame from server', frame)
                    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('Q'):
                        break
                client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ServerSecurityCam()
```

and this is the client:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle
import socket
import ctypes
import struct
import numpy as np
import cv2


class SecurityCamClient:

    def __init__(self):
        my_socket = socket.socket()
        my_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 65432))
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        self.ret, self.frame1 = self.cap.read()
        self.ret, self.frame2 = self.cap.read()
        while self.cap.isOpened():
            self.diff = cv2.absdiff(self.frame1, self.frame2)
            self.gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            self.blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(self.gray, (5, 5), 0)
            _, thresh = cv2.threshold(self.blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
            self.dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
            self.contours, _ = cv2.findContours(self.dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            for contour in self.contours:
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

                if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1300:
                    continue

                cv2.rectangle(self.frame1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(self.frame1, "Status: {}".format('Movement'), (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
                # Serialize frame
                data = pickle.dumps(self.frame1)

                # Send message length first
                message_size = struct.pack("L", len(data))

                # Then data
                my_socket.sendall(message_size + data)

            # cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.imshow("feed", self.frame1)
            self.frame1 = self.frame2
            self.ret, self.frame2 = self.cap.read()
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('Q'):
                break

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    md = SecurityCamClient()
```

Comment: Please provide explanations if the current behavior is not the required one. Any error messages ?

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't know how to do that :\